# Does $\mathbb R^n$ have the least upper bound property?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I don't know if this is an axiom for $\mathbb R^n$ (I know this property is an axiom for $\mathbb R$), and hence the question. Please note, I am considering the obvious partial ordering on $\mathbb R^n$ i.e. if $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$ with $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,...,y_n)$ then $x\leq y$ iff for all $i$, $x_i\leq y_i$ and $x<y$ iff $x\leq y$ and for some $i$, $x_i<y_i$.

More concretely, I am interested in the following question: If $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ is a bounded set, I would like to talk about $\sup A$ and $\inf A$, with regards to the mentioned partial order. Do they exist? And can I say that I can find sequences $a_m\in A$ and $b_m\in A$ such that $a_m\to \sup A$ and $b_m\to \sup B$? Will there be any problem in the topology considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this follows quite directly form the least upper bound property for $\mathbb R$.

However you're not guaranteed to have a sequence converging to the $\inf$ or $\sup$. You can for example take the set of $(t, -t)$ where $|t|\le 1$. The majorants of this set is $(x,y)$ such that $x\ge 1$ and $y\ge 1$. The least of these is $(1,1)$, but you can't make $(t_n, -t_n)\to (1,1)$ regardless of what sequence $t_n$ you choose.

Normally in general metric spaces one don't use the least upper bound property as much as one does in real analysis. The reason is partly the above failure, but also that it requires that the set is ordered which is normally not needed for what lub property is used for. Instead one uses the concept of completeness, the property that each Cauchy sequence is convergent.

Comment: Let me get this straight. For any bounded set, I can talk about maximal element and minimal element, under the partial order, right? They exist, right? I was thinking that maybe supremum and infimum would be the maximal and minimal elements themselves.

Comment: @LandonCarter It should obvious that maximal and minimal elements do not exists, not even close. One problem is that the order is *partial*, we can even have a set where you always have $a\not\le b\not\le a$ if $a\ne b$, for example the set I describe - then we could never have a maximal element.

Comment: @LandonCarter The use of least upper bounds in analysis is that it's "nearly maximal", that we have an upper bound that is at least near the set. Or that we can find a sequence in the set converging to $\sup$. In $\mathbb R^n$ this property fails which makes the least upper bound not as useful anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a direct product of complete lattices is a complete lattice. You can compute sup and inf component-wise.

No, the set $A=\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ is separated from $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Consider the set $A=\{(x,-x)\in \mathbb R^2 \mid -1\le x \le 1 \}$. It has a supremum but it is not the limit of anything from the set.

This problem is precisely why in analysis one rarely considers such a partial ordering on the product space (of arbitrary metric spaces). The topology associated with the ordering is only very loosely related to the product topology. A related issue is that of product of metric spaces, and the issue is resolved by using a norm. The (say, standard) norm on $\mathbb R^2$ Gives the correct topology, and has the property you are looking for.

Comment: OK, maybe I wasn't clear. I was talking about sup and inf not w.r.t the topology but w.r.t the ordering. Under partial ordering, bounded sets have maximal and minimal elements, right? Can we define sup and inf to be the maximal and minimal elements?

Comment: No, bounded sets need not have a maximum or a minimum. See the example I gave.